# How can I power a vanity light from a ceiling light switch circuit?

Tags: wiring, bathroom

I have power coming into a LED can light then to a regular bulb light then to a double switch (single gang). Then trying to use the second switch to power two other vanity lights.
How is this wired?

Comment: What does the second switch currently control? Can you post a picture of the inside of the switch box showing all the connections to both switches?

Comment: the second switch will control to vanity lights.

Comment: I know what you **want** it to do. But what does it do **now**? Or did you have a single switch and replaced it now with a double?

Comment: currently it will not turn the vanity lights on. there is power going to it but the light will not come on.

Comment: also i have the power running through a led can light, then to a regular light then to the double switch; however, the regular light barely lights up. But when I reach my hand closer to the light it gets brighter. not sure it this helps

Comment: Very strange about dim light. Starting point is to see wiring of the switches.

Comment: You've wired it in series. All house wiring should be in parallel. Please post a sketch of your situation. I suspect that the question is more than what you've told us.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring involved?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to identify lights that you want switched together with the new lights, and run a /2 cable from those lights to the new lights.

The new lights' black and white go to black and white on the cable.

In the old box, you look at where the black and white *from the lamp itself* go to.  The black and white from the new cable go to those same places.